# jQuery Validation Plugin with styled textboxes

Tags: jquery, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a textexbox that is in the middle of the a three-row, three column table.  The "outer" table cells are used to add some decoration to the textbox.  When the data entered into the texbox is invalid, the color of the textbox changes, as do the surrounding images.  Here's where my problem lies.  On the login page there is the username texbox, and password textbox.  If I hit submit with neither of them filled out the color of the texbox changes as do the images to show the field is required.  My problem is, how do I get them to change back to normal when the user enters some text?  I could write my own javascript to handle this, but I'm trying to use jQuery to validate, like the rest of the application.  Any ideas?

Here is what I have working right now:

```
        $.APP.login = $("#logOnDiv > form").validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            element.parents('table').removeClass('input-table');
            element.parents('table').addClass('invalid-input-table');
        },
        errorClass: "invalid-decorated-input"
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen to an event on the text box itself like `keypress`.  Assuming that each text box has a class called `isValidated` ...

```
$('.isValidated').keypress(function() {
  if($(this).val().length) { //we have text now
    $(this).parents('table.invalid-input-table').removeClass('invalid-input-table');
    //put any other code to remove other html elements (like the images here)
    //traversal would be from the text box, so you could do things like $(this).siblings('img').remove(), etc.
  }
});
```

There are more efficient ways to do this by using `live` events and adding the invalid classes to the text boxes themselves, but this should be enough unless you're talking about a very large number of fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not sure it is what I am looking for.  I know I can simply use classes to target the texbox, but that doesn't help because the images around the textxbo in the table also need to change.  I also don't know that key press is what I'm looking for because that doesn't provide any validation that text is actually being entered.

Comment: I expanded the answer to be a bit more robust.  Without your specific DOM, this is as specific as I can get.

Comment: The idea is this will be dynamic that can be used on each page.  However, your suggestion got me thinking, and I came up with this:        Ok, I give up trying to get code posted in this section.  Basically I used some of your code, with two changes.  I got rid of .parents and replaced it with closest, and I add a listener for the keypress event in the function that changes the class.